# Windows 7 cannot verify publisher of certain system executables, incl. cmd.exe

Tags: windows-7, uac

I was trying to run `cmd.exe` as administrator in Windows 7 and I noticed that Windows didn't recognize it as being published by Microsoft Windows as it normally does. I tried a bunch of other commands such as `taskmgr.exe` and `mspaint.exe` but had no luck (this is not a problem on another Windows 7 machine I have access to). Firefox, however, is correctly recognized as having been published by Mozilla Corporation. So it's not as if Windows's UAC is entirely confused. My first thought was that my machine is infected by some sort of malware. Is that a possibility or have I just messed up something in Windows that could be fixed relatively easily?

P.S. Non-native applications seem to be recognized properly: Spotify (Spotify AB), Chrome (Google Inc), Word (Microsoft Corporation), etc.

Comment: Can you by chance provide more information.  For example provide the information that does exist for those programs.

Answer (score 2):

An update to root certificates has caused problems for many Windows 7 systems this week.
Microsoft has issued an [update to reverse this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3024777). See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. An update restart was pending on my machine so I first restarted my computer after which everything is working fine. So I cannot confirm that it was this particular update that solved the issue or it was solved for some other reason.